# GET request method is returning the html template's name instead of redirecting to the template in Spring boot

Tags: html, spring-boot, rest, model

I recently started using Spring boot. I am trying to fetch the rows from the DB and trying to display the results on a webpage using the html file display.html.

In the control file, I have the following content:

```
package com.forms.demo.htmlExample.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.forms.demo.htmlExample.model.User;
import com.forms.demo.htmlExample.repo.UserRepository;
import com.forms.demo.htmlExample.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService service;        

    @RequestMapping("/displayUsers")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getUsers(Model model) {
        List<User> users= service.getUsers();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "display";
    }
```

My display.html (under the templates ) file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Display</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>

</table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        
    </tr>
    
    <tr th:each="usr:${users}">
        <td th:text=${usr.fname}></td>
        <td th:text=${usr.email}></td>
    </tr>

</body>
</html>
```

However when I am sending the url http://localhost:8080/displayUsers, it is returning "display" instead of taking me to the page display.html.

Can anyone say what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `@ResponseBody` in the `getUsers` method of the `IndexController` class, which is telling the Controller that object return should be serialized to JSON. In this case String "display" is getting serialized and returned as a String.  Remove @ResponseBody from the getUsers method and return the view name as String as in the updated code:

```
@RequestMapping("/displayUsers")
public String getUsers(Model model) {
    List<User> users= service.getUsers();
    model.addAttribute("users", users);
    return "display";
}
```

Comment: Hi salmnan94, Thanks for the input and it worked. So I understand @ResponseBody should be used only when we want to display the data in the json format or any such, right ?

Comment: @RDX When you want to return an Object in the form of JSON. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body#requestbody